# jQuery get value of generated hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I cannot figure it out how can i get the value of a hidden input which has been appended before.I mean i have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".form").append('<input type="hidden" id="inputhidden1" value="myvalue"> ');
    $(".form").submit(function () {
        console.debug($("#inputhidden1").val())
    });
});
```

The following code, when the form is submited will debug me the value as undefined. Why?

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, since the `"` are not escaped properly. Are you sure it is the same as your code?

Comment: Try this: `$(".form").append('<input type="hidden" id="inputhidden1" value="myvalue">');`

Comment: Also your input tag is missing a close.

Comment: it is not the same code , i've written this fast...

Comment: one of the significant aspects of jQuery.. is that you can chain your selectors.. like instead of calling `$('.form')` multiple times you can do this: `$('.form').append(....').submit(function() { }`

Answer (score 1):

Your script has syntax errors, try this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){// missing function
     $(".form").append("<input type='hidden' id='inputhidden1' value='myvalue'>");//missing closing tag, quotes error
     $(".form").submit(function()
        {
            console.debug($("#inputhidden1").val())
        });
});​
```

Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fsNZt/)

Answer (score 0):

there is an error in your code, you are not using document.ready correctly and you are using double quote inside double quote.
Is your form has a class named "form"?

Give your form an id, lets say you gave

```
<form id="formid" action="#">
       <input type="submit" value="Click Me"/>
</form>
```

now try this code in script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#formid").append("<input type='hidden' id='inputhidden1' value='myvalue'/>");
          $("#formid").submit(function(){
              console.debug($("#inputhidden1").val());
          });
    });
</script>
```

its printing the value = myvalue on debug console of firebug..